# Define multiple different lstm in keras or tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm

I am currently play with lstm and rnn for some time. I have tried them in both tensorflow and keras. However some thing makes me really confused. Like in tensorflow, if I want to define multiple rnn as decoder in a for loop, I can code as follow:

```
with tf.variable_scope("decoder-rnn") as vs:
    # We use an LSTM Cell

    cell_utterance = tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(hparams.rnn_dim,
                                             forget_bias=2.0,
                                             use_peepholes=True,
                                             state_is_tuple=True)


    # Run all utterances through the RNN batch by batch
    # TODO: Needs to be parallelized
    all_utterances_encoded = []
    for i in range(batch_size):


        temp_outputs, temp_states = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell_utterance, utterances_embedded[:,i],
                                                      utterances_len[i], dtype=tf.float32)
        all_utterances_encoded.append(temp_states[1]) # since it's a tuple, use the hidden states

    all_utterances_encoded = tf.stack(all_utterances_encoded, axis=0)
```

However, it seems that we use multiple rnn to wrap the same lstm. Is there any way that we can use different rnn to wrap different lstm?

The same issue goes with keras, when I use for loop to define ten GRU, the print out show there seems only two different GRU, can any one give some hints? Thanks.

```
for i in range(10):
gru = GRU(NUM_FILTERS,recurrent_activation='sigmoid',activation=None,return_sequences=False)#(embed)
print(gru)

<keras.layers.recurrent.GRU object at 0x7fcc1fef82b0>
<keras.layers.recurrent.GRU object at 0x7fcc1fef84a8>
<keras.layers.recurrent.GRU object at 0x7fcc1fef82b0>
<keras.layers.recurrent.GRU object at 0x7fcc1fef84a8>
<keras.layers.recurrent.GRU object at 0x7fcc1fef82b0>
<keras.layers.recurrent.GRU object at 0x7fcc1fef84a8>
<keras.layers.recurrent.GRU object at 0x7fcc1fef82b0>
<keras.layers.recurrent.GRU object at 0x7fcc1fef84a8>
<keras.layers.recurrent.GRU object at 0x7fcc1fef82b0>
<keras.layers.recurrent.GRU object at 0x7fcc1fef84a8>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you don't use the GRU layer after its creation and the only reference to that is the `gru` variable, it is destroyed after creating the next GRU layer in the next iteration of for loop. That's because there is no longer any reference to it and hence it is considered as a garbage. You can store all of them in a list to prevent this from happening:

```
gru_layers = []
for i in range(10):
    gru = GRU(NUM_FILTERS,recurrent_activation='sigmoid',activation=None,return_sequences=False)
    gru_layers.append(gru)
    print(gru)
```

Sample output:

```
<keras.layers.recurrent.GRU object at 0x7f8940398f98>
<keras.layers.recurrent.GRU object at 0x7f8940398ef0>
<keras.layers.recurrent.GRU object at 0x7f8940398400>
<keras.layers.recurrent.GRU object at 0x7f8940398978>
<keras.layers.recurrent.GRU object at 0x7f8940398a90>
<keras.layers.recurrent.GRU object at 0x7f89403b6048>
<keras.layers.recurrent.GRU object at 0x7f89403b6320>
<keras.layers.recurrent.GRU object at 0x7f89403b6278>
<keras.layers.recurrent.GRU object at 0x7f89403b6710>
<keras.layers.recurrent.GRU object at 0x7f89403b69b0>
```

Or better than that, if you intend to stack multiple GRU layers on top of each other, you can do this:

```
embed = Embedding(vocab_size, embed_dim)
prev_layer = embed
for i in range(10):
    gru = GRU(NUM_FILTERS,recurrent_activation='sigmoid',activation=None,return_sequences=True)(prev_layer)
    prev_layer = gru
```

Don't forget that when stacking RNN layers you should pass `return_sequences=True` to have the output of all the timesteps (except for the last layer which is not necessary to do so).

Comment: Thanks for great answer!